# AmazonClientManager - Issue with resumeSessionWithCompletionHandler in AWSCognito GPlus Login iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-ios, aws-ios

Hi all am facing some problem with resumeSessionWithCompletionHandler in AmazonClientManager for GPlus AWSCognito login in iOS. But the same resume session works fine for Facebook Login. Can u please help me on this. This is the code I have used in iOS,

```
 [[AmazonClientManager sharedInstance] googleLoginFromView:self
           withCompletionHandler:^id(AWSTask *task) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{   
                   [[AmazonClientManager sharedInstance]
                         resumeSessionWithCompletionHandler:^id(AWSTask *task) {
                               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
                                   // Dataset successfully refreshed
                                   // Refresh your credentials here
                               }); 
                           return nil; 
                    }];

            }); return nil;

  }];
```

It would be helpful for me if you have an idea to fix this.